# Angular 2 Insert DOM into InfoWindow element that was created by Google Maps V3 api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular

I am working with the Google Maps V3 inside Angular 2 and I am currently attempting to find a solution for populating InfoWindows with bound links and input values.  When an InfoWindow element is created it is a new DOM element and according to Angular 2 docs binding to a DOM element that did not exist on the initialization of the app is not supported.  Is there a way to insert or inject bound elements into the newly created DOM, or have a pre-created element containing the bound elements that can be moved into the InfoWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you should use *dynamic components creation* in this case. Just try smth like this in your service or component, which knows, when you have to render your content:

```
import {ComponentResolver, ComponentFactory, ComponentRef, ApplicationRef, Injector} from '@angular/core';

export class SomeServiceOrComponent {
  constructor(private resolver:ComponentResolver, private injector:Injector, private appRef:ApplicationRef) {
  }

  renderComponent() {
    return this.resolver
        .resolveComponent(YourDynamicComponentClass)
        .then((factory:ComponentFactory<YourDynamicComponentClass>) => {
            let cmpRef:ComponentRef<YourDynamicComponentClass> =
                factory.create(this.injector, null, '.infoWindowsDOMSelector');
            (<any>this.appRef)._loadComponent(cmpRef);
            return cmpRef;
        });
  }
}
```

and just call this method, whether you need it.

`(<any>this.appRef)._loadComponent(cmpRef)` is a trick from prev versions of RC, but maybe soon it should be resolved

Comment: I'm fairly new to Angular in general, so pardon my ignorance.  Would this example be built into the existing class, or does SomeServiceOrComponent refer to a utility service for rendering dynamic content?

Comment: Ah I got it to work, thanks for the help.  I guess the only hitch right now is how would I pass data to the new component from the parent as an @Input using this method?

Comment: Got this to work also buy adding  cmpRef.instance.inputData = data; after creating cmpRef;

Comment: Yes, you've found it, that's cool )
`instance` - is only one way to access your component, if it was created dynamically, like this

Comment: I really appreciate this topic, unfortunately some time has passed and angular has been updated...I am using angular 8 and cannot get it working...an update would be very nice!

Comment: I have the same issue... I need to render and Angular componente inside a InfoWindow. The component has an @Input() data: any property. I'm currently using Angular 11.